# Ghostscript convert to pdfA

Tags: ghostscript

My client update the version of ghostscript to 9.52, so in version 9.26 I use this command to convert a pdf to PDFA

```
gs -dPDFA=1 -dNOOUTERSAVE -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dAutoRotatePages=/All -dAutoRotatePages=/PageByPage -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o %s -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 %s
```

And now dont work, I look at the ghostscript page but don't find anything about this, I try to run gs -help and don't show anything about PDFA/

Output

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.52 (2020-03-19)
Copyright (C) 2020 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 11.
Page 1
Querying operating system for font files...
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Loading NimbusSans-Regular font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/share/ghostscript/9.52/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Regular... 5166408 3765122 3714160 2131206 4 done.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Loading NimbusSans-Bold font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/share/ghostscript/9.52/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Bold... 5333904 3971793 3887064 2279347 4 done.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Loading NimbusRoman-Regular font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/share/ghostscript/9.52/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Regular... 5582200 4214307 4074376 2452321 4 done.
Substituting font Helvetica-Oblique for Arial-ItalicMT.
Loading NimbusSans-Italic font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/share/ghostscript/9.52/Resource/Font/NimbusSans-Italic... 5790096 4425213 4329920 2696833 4 done.
Page 2
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Oblique for Arial-ItalicMT.
Substituting font Times-Italic for TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
Loading NimbusRoman-Italic font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/share/ghostscript/9.52/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Italic... 6100144 4722942 4331040 2687157 4 done.
Page 3
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Oblique for Arial-ItalicMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Substituting font Times-Bold for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Loading NimbusRoman-Bold font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/share/ghostscript/9.52/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-Bold... 6369792 5000393 4526128 2895926 4 done.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Page 4
Substituting font Helvetica-Oblique for Arial-ItalicMT.
Substituting font Times-BoldItalic for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldItalicMT.
Loading NimbusRoman-BoldItalic font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/share/ghostscript/9.52/Resource/Font/NimbusRoman-BoldItalic... 6659256 5279321 4313104 2696170 4 done.
Substituting font Times-Bold for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Substituting font Courier for CourierNewPSMT.
Loading NimbusMonoPS-Regular font from /usr/local/Cellar/ghostscript/9.52/share/ghostscript/9.52/Resource/Font/NimbusMonoPS-Regular... 6949104 5565124 4881808 3220775 4 done.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Page 5
Substituting font Times-Bold for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Page 6
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Substituting font Times-Bold for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Oblique for Arial-ItalicMT.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Substituting font Times-Italic for TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
Page 7
Substituting font Times-Bold for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Oblique for Arial-ItalicMT.
Substituting font Courier for CourierNewPSMT.
Substituting font Times-Italic for TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Page 8
Substituting font Times-Bold for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Substituting font Times-Italic for TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Page 9
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Page 10
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Times-Bold for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Substituting font Courier for CourierNewPSMT.
Page 11
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Substituting font Times-Bold for TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Oblique for Arial-ItalicMT.
Substituting font Times-Roman for TimesNewRomanPSMT.
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Substituting font Times-Italic for TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT.
```

Comment: Without seeing the output of the command or the input file, its rather hard to make any comments, especially since 'don't work' doesn't really convey any detail. A few points; don't use -dNOOUTERSAVE, You've got three invocations of -dAutoRotatePages in there with different values. You shouldn't specify ProcessColorModel. You appear to be using the same filename for input and output, which won;t work. You aren't executing a definitions file (or don't seem to be) to set up the PDF/A definitions.

Comment: @KenS i put the output and remove the -dNOOUTERSAVE

Comment: The output you've pasted doesn't indicate any errors, so in what way 'don't work' ?